# Laravel Testing - How to run command with RefreshDatabase with seed

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

in Laravel I need to run MY CUSTOM COMMAND after refreshdatabase and db:seed

- new database
- migration
- seed
- MY COMMAND

this test finish successfully when i run all these steps manually

I write this test code.

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    
    public function testDbSeed()
    {
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
        $resultAsText = Artisan::output();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
```

all tables deleted and then run all my migrations successfully.

My question is How to run my CUSTOM command after seed?

> php artisan permission:sync

```
    public function testPermissionSync()
    {
        Artisan::call('permission:sync');
        $resultAsText = Artisan::output();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
```

after this command we can open main page in ourlocalsite.local/

```
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {

        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

but this test not passed and assert error is 403

(when i do these steps manually this command run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `setUp()` method that triggered before any test begins.

but don not forget to call the parent setup

```
public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
    }
```

there is also `tearDown()` function that triggered after test ended